# Access Expression Editor - Newbie to access reports

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2007, expression

I am new to Access reports and forms. Yes I hate admitting it. I am familiar with the database part but not with reports and forms.

I have come across this peculiar expression in Access expression builder which i cant deconstruct

=IIf(([value1] & ""="") Or ([value2] & ""=""),"",[value3])

Please understand that I have sufficient experience with Crystal Reports and i understand what an iif statement is .

But I have not come across anything like this

1. What exactly does  & ""="" do?
2. Is this some sort of regular expression in Access?
3. Can you help me by providing links so that I can read up on this in depth?

Thanks a ton in advance
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is appending an empty string to the value to avoid Null.

You could say it this way:

```
Value Is Null Or Value = ""
```

Further explanation re comment

Let us say Value1 is Null

```
Value1 is not equal to ""
```

However

```
Value1 & "" is equal to ""
```

Let us say Value1 = ""

```
Value1 is not equal to Null
```

However

```
Value1 & "" is equal to ""
```

Let us say Value1 = "abc"

```
Value1 & "" is equal to "abc"
```

Comment: What I can understand is that the expression attaches a 
"" to the string by using the & operator. But how exactly does it check for null? Would be a great help if you could go into this in more detail. Also, can i use Isnull()?

Comment: I am not sure what I can add to my explanation. You are looking at ""="", but what you should be seeing is `[Value1] & "" = ""`. This is a shortcut so that Value1 is never equal to Null. If it is Null, adding an empty string ( & "") will change it to an empty string.

Comment: Could not I have said [Value1] & """" as well?

Comment: No, that is not an empty string. You can say vbNullString in some circumstances, that is equal to "".

Comment: Oh my God! Now I get it! its [Value1] & "" = "". I have to read this  as follows (&"")   (=   ""). I was reading it as & ("" = ""). The brackets i have added just for explaining my confusion! Duh! Thanks a ton Remou!